# Accessing value from first array element - filtered

Tags: elasticsearch

After spent weekend looking for answer I decided to ask you for help. I have an index with products. Variants are nested list of objects in the products and i sort them by stock quantity and some other conditions while feeding index.
I'm tryin to sort products by value of first variant in elastic resposne (including filters passed in query). Here is a example what i'm looking for.
Shortened elastic response structure:

```
{
    "id": 6346,
    "name": "name",
    "variants": [
        {
            "variant_id": 1,
            "stock_quantity": 20,
            "price": 9.9
        },
        {
            "variant_id": 2,
            "stock_quantity": 15,
            "price": 20.9
        },
        {
            "variant_id": 3,
            "stock_quantity": 0,
            "price": 16.9
        }
    ]
}
```

Let's filter list by price gte 15:

```
{
    "id": 6346,
    "name": "name",
    "variants": [
        {
            "variant_id": 2,
            "stock_quantity": 15,
            "price": 20.9
        },
        {
            "variant_id": 3,
            "stock_quantity": 0,
            "price": 16.9
        }
    ]
}
```

Now i try to sort products by price of first variant from response. What have i tried to do so far?

Sort by script

```
"sort": 
     {
       "_script": {
         "order": "desc",
         "type": "number",
         "script": {
          "source": "return params['_source']['variants'][0].gross_price"
         }
       }
     }
```

That worked until i started filtering the list. In variants.gross_price gte 15 case, script returns value from the source document: 9.9, not 20.9 as I expected. I'm skipping the fact that ref the source is not recommended for performance reasons.

Sort by field

```
"sort": 
{
      "variants.gross_price": {
        "nested": {
          "path": "variants",
          "filter": {
            "bool": {
              "filter": [               
                {
                  "range": {
                    "variants.gross_price": {
                      "gt": "15"
}
[...]
```

I don't know why but this way i get no price of first variant from the response but the price of cheapest variant in product - 16.9 in this case.

I also added flag 'include_in_parent' to variants and try to get value by "doc['variants.gross_price'].values" in script, but same effect as first one.

So.. What else could i try to do?

**UPDATE**
Max_children from 6.5 release is what i'm looking for.

Comment: Concerning the last point: 
   " When you get a document back from Elasticsearch, any arrays will be in the same order as when you indexed the document. The _source field that you get back contains exactly the same JSON document that you indexed.

    However, arrays are indexed—made searchable—as multivalue fields, which are unordered. At search time, you can’t refer to “the first element” or “the last element.” Rather, think of an array as a bag of values."

Answer (score 2):

You can try the below script.

```
"sort": {
        "_script": {
            "type": "number",
            "script": {
                "inline": "if(doc['variants.gross_price'].value > 15) {max = doc['variants.gross_price'].value;}, abs(max)",
            "order" : asc
            }
       }
   }
```

Comment: That's should work but but case with price in my post is only an example what I'm looking for. My variant object has about 10 or more different filter option. I'm afraid that I would create too many IF-ology in my code if I would like to pass each condition to script. 

Isn't there any way to get value from first variant of my filtered response? Without sorting them before? Something like response.variants[0].price.

Thanks for reply anyway.

Comment: This wont work, op want to "to sort products by value of first variant in elastic", according to my comment (from es documentation) the solution will have to loop on variant_id asc after the gross_price filter, before select the gross_price and desc it in the result.

Answer (score 1):

Here we are, please use java max value instead of 999 and you should be ok ;). You have to loop on id to find the min with a gross price >15. And return the gross price assiociated. Please tell us if it works, i tested on my data and seems to be ok.

```
{
  "query": {
    "nested": {
      "path": "variants",
      "query": {
        "range": {
          "variants.gross_price": {
            "gt": "15"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "sort": [
    {
      "_script": {
        "script": {
          "inline": " int minima = 999; long result = -1; if (doc['variants.gross_price'].value > 15) { if (doc['variants.variant_id'].value < minima) minima = doc['variants.variant_id'].value; result = doc['variants.gross_price'].value;} \n return result",
          "lang": "painless"
        },
        "order": "desc",
        "nested_path": "variants",
        "type": "number"
      }
    }
  ],
  "from": 0,
  "size": 10
}
```

Comment: Thanks for reply but like i said there is a lot of filtering combinations that may change variants from response. Variants contains nested list of attributes and you can also filter by them. I used price as example to visualize my problem in simplest way. I don't know if using script to sort my products would be good in this case? There would be a lot of conditions.

Comment: If you need to order using sub in a nested field like your ticket i thinck you have to make script for each one. Your request is really specitic and functionnal. Maybe if you describe your context and needs we could find a better data modelisation.

Comment: I updated first post, max_children from newest elastic release is exactly what i'm looking for. Thanks for your replies anyway!